# How to create a new Q# Project in VSCode

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, quantum-computing, q#

I am trying to figure out how to start writing code using Microsoft Q# and QDK, but am running into a lot of issues as there aren't any good documents that help you set up projects from scratch. I tried running `dotnet new console` and that created a `Program.cs` file, which for Q# needs to be `Program.qs`, I tried simply changing the name of that file but it gave this error:

```
CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point
```

Does anyone know how to setup a Q# project from scratch in VS Code? I am really struggling with this

Comment: How to install and use the Q# compiler and QuantumSDK is explained on Microsoft's GitHub account: [Q# Compiler](https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-compiler), [Quantum SDK](https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp-compiler/tree/main/src/QuantumSdk).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the official QDK documentation? [Write a Q# standalone program to run on a local quantum simulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/how-to-command-line-local) has the instructions for VS Code.

1. If you're using command line with VS Code, you can run `dotnet new console -lang Q# -o NewProjectName` - that should create a folder `NewProjectName` with .csproj and .qs files.
2. If you're using command palette in VS Code, click `View -> Command Palette` and select `Q#: Create New Project`, then click `Standalone console application` and navigate to the location to save the project.
3. The way I sometimes use is copy an existing project similar to what I want; your .csproj file will look something like this

   ```xml
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.Quantum.Sdk/0.21.2111177148">
     <PropertyGroup>
       <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
       <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
     </PropertyGroup>
   </Project>
   ```